# Why would a PHP script run repeatedly for some Windows users using my Office Add-in?

Tags: php, internet-explorer-11, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have a simple javascript call in my Word add-in to update user preferences.

Users on macOS and (similar code) Chrome Extension use this code and it fires the server-side php script once.

Some Windows users get hundreds of script calls - even (seemingly) when they don't have Office open.

The problem is hard to sleuth because I can't reproduce. But I can see the issue in my logs and also server load.

I feel that the culprit is IE11, which Office Add-ins use on Windows...

It's as if the process fires once, and then ghosts repeatedly...here's what it looks like in the log:

> [13/Oct/2019 06:46:50] (2updateUserDetail) Starting
>   updateUserDetail...user/sender: 8516 / updateWordPrefs [13/Oct/2019
>   06:46:50] (2updateUserDetail) Starting updateUserDetail...user/sender:
>   8516 / updateWordPrefs [13/Oct/2019 06:46:50] (2updateUserDetail)
>   Starting updateUserDetail...user/sender: 8516 / updateWordPrefs
>   [13/Oct/2019 06:46:50] (2updateUserDetail) Starting
>   updateUserDetail...user/sender: 8516 / updateWordPrefs [13/Oct/2019
>   06:46:50] (2updateUserDetail) Starting updateUserDetail...user/sender:
>   8516 / updateWordPrefs

I'll get 50 or 80 of these in a row, all with the same time stamp...then another 50 or 80 with a time stamp a second or two later.

Here is the section of PHP code:

```
if ($sender == 'updateWordPrefs'){
    //  Update from Word app
    $userID  = $arrUser['userID'];
    $userPrefWordInline  = $arrUser['userPrefWordInline'];
    $userPrefWordLog  = $arrUser['userPrefWordLog'];

    $log->lwrite('Starting updateUserDetail...user/sender: '. $userID . ' / ' . $sender);

    $query = "UPDATE users SET user_pref_word_inline = " . $userPrefWordInline . ",  user_pref_word_log = " . $userPrefWordLog . " WHERE  userID = " . $userID;

    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
      echo "\n\nWord prefs set...";
    } else{
      echo "ERROR: Was not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
        mysqli_close($connection);
}   //  End updateWordPrefs sub
```

Any ideas/suggestions appreciated. I'm trying to work through affected users to diagnose but that is a slow and inefficient process - to say the least.

**Update**
From user feedback I'm believing that the PHP script called by my Javascript runs after Microsoft Word is closed...maybe even after IE11 is closed.

I've had users clear IE11 cache and still the process runs...which makes me feel that IE11 is starting the process, somehow, and then my server just keeps going.

Again, many many users on this code...but only Windows users so affected. And not all of them.

One other pattern: the blasts of php calls run, then stop (maybe my server killing the process automatically?) then start again roughly an hour later.

I'm definitely into the territory of sacrificing goats to the gods of Javascript and PHP...but this makes me think something is started on my server and somehow my PHP server continues to try and complete...even though the sending machine has been force-stopped and/or cache cleared...

Comment: Open the Task Manager and see if there are any instances of **Desktop App Web Viewer** running. Also, checkout this article, [Browsers used by Office Web Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins), to see if which browser the add-in is using on the affected and unaffected Windows computers.

Comment: Did you seen any error messages in console on problematic machines? can you tell us, which OS users are using? You said some users are having this issue. Do you mean all the Windows OS users or some of Windows OS users? If some windows OS users are facing this issue than you can find the difference in the configuration of their OS may help to give any hint about the cause of the issue.

Comment: I checked your update but not sure what causing this issue. As we are not available with that same environment and add on to make a test It is hard to predict about the cause. That small block of code not giving any idea about the issue.